# Summing fields of a list in Java

Tags: java

I would like to understand how to sum fields of a list of items in Java.

Let's say that I have this code:

```
Person p1 = new Person("someone", 13, 1.55);
Person p2 = new Person("Jack", 14, 1.39);
Person p3 = new Person("John", 10, 1.39);

List<Person> personsList = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3);
```

I tried getting `sum` like this, but it doesn't work:

```
int sum = personsList.sum(p[2]);
```

Comment: Question is not clear enough. What do you want to do ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I tried getting sum like this, but it doesn't work:
>
> ```
> int sum = personsList.sum(p[2]);
> ```

The syntax for using `sum` is different:

```
int sum = lst.stream().mapToInt(p -> p.getProp2()).sum();
```

where `getProp2()` is the name of the getter of the `int` property that you wish to sum.

Comment: @user3378649 Ahh. That guy deleted his comment. This won't work before Java 8 :)

Answer (score 2):

Asuming that the second parameter is the age, and that you have a `int getAge()` method into Person class that return it, you can just use the stream API:

`int sum = personsList.stream().mapToInt( Person::getAge ).sum();`